# rep and/or seq function to create continuously reducing vector?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a vector from 1 to 5,

```
 a<-c(1:5)
```

What I need to do is to repeat the vector by losing one element continuously. That is, the final outcome should be like

```
1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 1 2 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can reverse the vector and apply `sequence`

```
sequence(rev(a))
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 1 2 1
```

---

Or another option is `toeplitz`

```
m1 <- toeplitz(a)
m1[lower.tri(m1, diag=TRUE)]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 1 2 1
```

Comment: @SandipanDey  I think you need a reverse

Comment: yes may be this `unlist(Map(rev, Map(seq, 5:1, 1)))` or can be simpler? your solutions are just awesome.

Comment: This variation of @SandipanDey's solution works for me: `unlist(Map(seq,5:1))`

Comment: @akrun Thanks so much. It seems `sequence` only works for the case of decrease by 1, but `toeplitz` function works for every case. I believe you helped me many times. I really appreciate it.